# open the user's client with attachment

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, coding-style

I have below code to send an email from browser client.

```html
<a href="mailto:one@two.com,two@three.com?cc=one@two.com?subject=Comments from MailTo Syntax Page">Send Mail</a>
```

However, I am looking for an email app (Outlook) which should pop up with recipient, text and attachment. After that, all that is left to do for me is pressing "send" in my outlook.

I've been trying for a while, but I couldn't find a solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

While Recipients, Subject and Body are supported in the [RFC mailto](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2368.html) url syntax and implemented by some clients (please note the correct encoding and escaping of special characters like spaces), Attachments are not supported at all.

That would be difficult also, how would you know which (local) file path to pick? Also, the client would open up a potential security risk.

Comment: I will be getting the file from a server and the same I want to attach to mail.

Comment: So you say, the server could return the File Path "_C:\Files\report.pdf_" for example, and you want to select this file path from the Users Harddrive? Allowing Functionality like this would be a clear security breach, so the protocols and clients don't support that by purpose. For the same reasons, it's not possible to prefill a `<input type="file" />` etc. At some point, the user will need to select the file manually.